# Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

I am getting a NullPointerException when calling a webservice from client.

**Stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
at $Proxy30.service(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Impossible to answer NPE without looking at your code

Comment: Please post the relevant section of code here.

Comment: I updated the codes. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use tool like wireshark to read the request and response, It may be helpful to find out what is going wrong. It shows sever side exception etc..

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're missing a jar to support the SOAP call.
I added this to my pom.xml to get rid of it:

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.8</version>
  </dependency>
```

Mind you, my soap call still failed, but maybe for other reasons:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:223)
```